# How to change the default setting '-DskipTests=true' during Heroku deployment?

Tags: testing, heroku, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Java project from Beanstalk using Heroku. But during the deployment process, the tests are skipped by default. I am aware that the default settings for Dskiptests is true. Is it possible to run tests using Heroku? Where do I change the settings to overwrite the default settings.
Here is how the build is started by default:

output -----> Java app detected

output -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done

output -----> Executing: mvn -B -DskipTests=true clean install

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```
$ heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS=""
```

For more information see:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java#customize-maven

Answer (score 1):

Mine was working perfectly with out any change, suddenly stopped. Tried bellow and worked

`heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="-DskipTests=false"`

btw I tried to set empty string as the value of `MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS` did not worked.

In case you want to know current value of all variable try:

`heroku run printenv`

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS in the [Heroku Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/).
[image]